# WIX dotnet publish working but transforming it into MsBuild fails to build

Tags: c#, msbuild

I keep going around the circle with my WiX project. It used to work fine with a "dotnet publish" command but we had to integrate a COM Object so now the dotnet publish fails to run. .NET Core does not support publishing COM objects.

So searching online lead me to a way of achieving this using msbuild (this is what publish from VS does, that works properly).

So I setup my msbuild command

[image]

Command looks like this.

```
msbuild 'D:\ProjectToDeploy.csproj' /property:DeployOnBuild=true /property:Configuration=Release  /property:Platform=x64 /property:OutputPath='D:\Publish'
```

Like I said this runs properly in Developer Powershell in VS 2022 Community.

Now in my WiX project I have the following code

```
 <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
      <PropertyGroup>
          <DefineConstants>BasePath=$(SolutionDir)\Publish</DefineConstants>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <!--clean the Publish Folder -->
      <Exec Command="rd /s /q $(SolutionDir)\Publish" />
      <!--publish the app-->
      <Exec Command="msbuild 'D:\ProjectToBuild.csproj' /property:DeployOnBuild=true /property:Configuration=Release  /property:Platform=x64 /property:OutputPath='D:\Publish'" />
      <HeatDirectory
          OutputFile="UCAEKeyStoreGenerated.wxs"
          DirectoryRefId="INSTALLFOLDER"
          ComponentGroupName="UCAEKeyStoreAPI"
          SuppressCom="true"
          Directory="$(SolutionDir)\Publish"
          SuppressFragments="true"
          SuppressRegistry="true"
          SuppressRootDirectory="true"
          AutoGenerateGuids="false"
          GenerateGuidsNow="true"
          ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)"
          PreprocessorVariable="var.BasePath">
      </HeatDirectory>
  </Target>
```

This throws an error into the console
"'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Which made me believe that msbuild is not in EnvironmentPath so I've added it there but no luck.

Then I tried to specified the full path of MSBuild

This does not work either.

What am I missing? how do I do an "exec command with msbuild" ?